# How can I hide the code from Chrome dev tools source?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

In the developer tools I can see my react.js code from src folder.
How can I hide it for other?

https://prnt.sc/onb72q

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue.
Please try following:

package.json

```
scripts: {
  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
}
```

or in .env file

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Please check this url.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4162

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CRA(create react app) and build your project then you only deploy the webpack build output - if you still don't have a deployment process and you are uploading the entire project including the build directory - so you can also disable source maps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand anything said here.

- I also had this problem, but I was able to solve it with [@Yerycs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59491276/14508232) above.
I created a .env file and pasted `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` there, and it worked!